# CSS: Text in DIV is Getting Cut Off

Tags: html, css, facebook, layout

I'm working on integrating a jQuery plugin that hides parts of a page until the user clicks a "Like Button".

Part of the Facebook widget's text is getting cut off. I've played around with the CSS, but can't get it to display fully.

If the width of a container is set correctly, what else could cause text to get cut-off?

Example: http://go.mouseflow.com/like/

Notice how it says "313 peo" when it should say "313 people like this page." I checked the source and the text is there, it's just not visible.

Comment: Have you tried `overflow:visible;` on the widget container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the reason is here:

```
.ui-locker-facebook .fb-like span {
    height: 24px !important;
    overflow: hidden;   /*change to 'visible'*/
}
```