# Words cut off at the end of lines - only in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I am creating a short and relatively simple website for a summer project about the book Red October (located at http://dragonmath.net/summer_project_2016/summary/). The website is not complete (it is missing content, pictures, and is not yet fully responsive), but before I finish any more, I would like to fix a bug. The website appears fine in all browsers except Safari. When Safari is over 1242px wide, some of the words at the ends of the line cut off.

Originally I believed that it might be the font that was the problem, but a little bit of testing showed that the words were cut off with many fonts, all the fonts I tried. Another interesting point is that some words extend past where the cut off words are cut off. This makes me believe that it doesn't likely have to do with the `width` of the element, but I am not sure.

I also noticed that the website seems to be wider in Safari, The `(min-width)` in the `@media` tag was able to be smaller in Chrome, but had to be wider in Safari. I don't know if this contributes to the words being cut off only in Safari, but I thought it might help explain the problem more completely.

I found several other articles with seemingly similar problems, but none of the suggested fixes helped my problem.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135659/css-text-in-div-is-getting-cut-off) and [this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/) both deal with `overflow`, or `text-overflow` neither of which fixed my problem. The css in my website still has `overflow: visible` in it.

The website from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605345/text-cut-off-in-safari-only) is no longer at the link provided, but I would imagine that the change to the answer was adding `width: 100%;`. I tried that, but it didn't have any effect on the text being cut off. [This MacRumors article](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/maddening-css-issue-text-cut-off-height-etc.337376/) seems to provide a similar answer to the question (changing to `height: 100%;` in this case). This article also mentions the fact that the text *wasn't* cut off in Safari (opposite of what I am finding).

I have tried Googling every possible way to put my problem that I can think of, but nothing has turned up. I have also searched Stack Overflow extensively for any reason that this could be happening. While it is hard to create a short piece of code that recreates the problem (because the problem only happens in Safari) below is all the html and css that should be causing the problem. The full code for my webpage can be found at http://dragonmath.net/summer_project_2016/summary/

```css
.mainSection {
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
}

.sectionContentContainer {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-left: 40px;
 width: 560px;
 overflow: visible;
}

.sectionParagraph {
 font-weight: 400px;
 font-size: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 40px;
 word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="mainSection">
  <div class="sectionContentContainer">
    <p class="sectionParagraph">The content goes here, but sometimes when the content stretches onto multiple lines, it cuts off random words in Safari.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

As far as I know, that is all the css that could impact the text. Just for background, the text has an image next to it and the image and the text are surrounded by `<main>` tags. The main is set to have `min-height: calc(100% - 160px; 
height: auto;
width: 100%;`

Here are some images of what happens:
[image: With other font]
[image: With regular font]

Any help would be great (and if any clarification is needed, ask in the comments).

Comment: I ran in the same problem.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in _Apple Webkit_ (Safari on Mac and all iPad browsers) related to `word-spacing` property: it does not update line wrapping, resulting in the words being cut.
You can set `text-overflow: ellipsis` to have an extra proof of the issue.